# Tools similar to HTTP Watch or YSlow for Google Chrome browser

Tags: debugging, google-chrome

Hi We are testing our app in Google chrome for support. The basic loading is in scrambled
and all the pages are in total CSS mess which we need to clean up unfortunately.For this I require a tool which works similar to firebug for Mozilla.Also to check  headers, cookies, caching and POST data ,compression, redirection & chunked encoding a similar tool to HTTP watch is also desired. Any suggestions.Thanks

Comment: Just an update I started using developer Tools which is in built but not comfortable with it but  I see there is no option to aviod it

Comment: Don't understand why this hasn't been upvoted at all.

Comment: Ohh how times have changed, chrome v23 dev tools make firefox/firebug feel old and busted (minus fancy 3d page inspector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has a [whole page](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) on this subject (along with the announcement that speed will be considered in ranking pages):

- Page Speed, an open source Firefox/Firebug add-on that evaluates the performance of web pages and gives suggestions for improvement.
- YSlow, a free tool from Yahoo! that suggests ways to improve website speed.
- WebPagetest shows a waterfall view of your pages' load performance plus an optimization checklist.
- In Webmaster Tools, Labs > Site Performance shows the speed of your website as experienced by users around the world as in the chart below. We've also blogged about site performance.

Answer (score 11):

Chrome comes with a Firebug equivalent built-in. Just right-click to `inspect element` and you should see the debugger.

Then install "[Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/)" and you will have profiling tools.

Comment: Thanks..I was already using inspect element tool.Just to be sure that any other tools are available or not

Comment: Just to note, the inspector has an "Audits" tab that works similar to YSlow.

Answer (score 4):

Try the inspector. It has basically the same feature set as Firebug, and is built-in (it comes with pretty much every WebKit-based browser, so you'll find it in Safari too).

Right-click on something and choose "Inspect Element", or go to the Document-icon menu and look at the Developer sub menu.

Comment: dev-channel version of chrome has some improvements in dev-tools part against the release.

Answer (score 3):

YSlow for Google Chrome was launched last week - http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2011/03/yslow-for-chrome/

Other than that, you can try using Google sped tracer(it works only in Chrome dev version).

Answer (score 2):

If you want Firebug for Chrome, try Firebug Lite: getfirebug.com/firebuglite (can't post more than one link, huh), and here's a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bnbbfjbeaefgipfjpdabmpadaacmafkj).

Comment: Thanks,BTW how did you come across this question which was posted moths earlier

Comment: been looking for posts about speed tracer :)

Answer (score 1):

Open "Developer Tools" in menu 'View' -> 'Developer'. It will give you a bunch of tabs. Click on "Resources" and then "enable" it (it's disabled by default). Chrome will start tracking http traffics and give you the info (almost) as rick as you can get from HttpWatch.

I'm using Chrome 8.0.